# Binary Partitioning n sorted data points in to b Buckets in `O(b.log(n))`

Tags: algorithm

Given sorted randomly accessible input data (a sorted array) of size n, I'd like to partition this in to buckets using a parameterised *partitioning function*. I want the result back as an array of indexes to the bucket edges.

The *partitioning function* returns a bool to indicate if too values should be in the same partition or not.

Note that prior to partitioning, we don't know how many buckets will be required:

- It is possible that all the input should be placed in a single bucket.
- It may be the case that every input needs its own bucket.
- Perhaps the first value needs one bucket and the whole remainder of the array is in a second bucket.

… this is not know before running the partitioning algorithm.

As a concrete example, lets say we have the partitioning function:

```
sameBucket(a, b) = (a/10 == b/10)
```

Where `/` is integer division (it rounds down). So

```
sameBucket(0,1) == yes
sameBucket(1,2) == yes
sameBucket(0,9) == yes
sameBucket(0,10) == no
```

The partition function tells us `0` and `10` should not be placed in to the same bucket.

Consider this input array shown with its indexes underneath for clarity (I assume a "past the end" index called end):

```
[1, 3, 7, 14, 90, 91, 92, 93, 95, 99]
 0  1  2  3   4   5   6   7   8   9   end
```

For this data, the elements that are members of a new bucket are indicated with a `^`:

```
[1, 3, 7, 14, 90, 91, 92, 93, 95, 99]
 0  1  2  3   4   5   6   7   8   9   end
 ^        ^   ^                       ^
```

If I use the partition function above, I'd get back just the indexes that begin a new bucket:

```
[0, 3, 4, end]
```

Each index in the result array represents the first element that the bucket function says is not in the same bucket as the element before it.

- The whole data is represented by the range `0…<end`.
- The range `0…<3` are the numbers `[1, 3, 7]`, which are all `0`, when divided by `10`.
- The range `3…<4` is the single number `14`, which is `1` when divided by `10`.
- The range `4…<end` are the numbers `[90, 91, 92, 93, 95, 99]`, which are all `0` when divided by `10`.

I believe a modified binary search should be able to perform this partitioning efficiently. For `n` input values, and `b` output buckets, the run time should be at worst `O(b.log(n))`. Does any one have an algorithm for it, even just the name, so I can look it up?

Comment: I think you left out some key assumptions. Is the array of values sorted? Is `sameBucket` transitive? Must it also be reflexive? If a < b < c and `sameBucket(a,b)` is false, does it imply that `sameBucket(a,c)` must be false as well?

Comment: Yes, sorted: :-) Check the second word of the post (which was honestly in the original cut prior to edit). You're totally right about the later points… I'm not sure. I was thinking perhaps I should have expressed `sameBucket` as similar to the `<` used for ordering the input, but somehow "weaker" – `sameBucket` in the example _doesn't_ say `1 < 9`, but _does_ say `1 < 10`.

Comment: Yes – sameBucket would definitely be transitive. And yes, it's also reflexive as you describe. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Does any given partition consist only of sequential elements, as with your example?

Comment: My last point wasn't about reflexivity (which means `sameBucket(x, x)` is true for all values of x). I am not sure if the property that I describe has a name. Basically, it allows no gaps: if the input sequence is sorted, and items at indexes `low` and `high` both go to one bucket, all items between them must go to the same bucket as well.

Comment: Yes, @Dukeling, partitions are always sequential elements, as in the example.

Comment: *nods* to @dasblinkenlight, right, I'm also not sure if there is a term. @dukeling is asking the same thing, I think: "Does any given partition consist only of sequential elements"? I was trying to get at this above with reference to `sameBucket` being "like" an inequality. It's kind of embedded in to the same inequality used to sort the input, but its somehow weaker – two elements can sort differently but be in the same buckets. However, two elements in different buckets must sort differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving this problem efficiently requires an assumption that if elements at two ends of a sorted range belong to the same bucket according to `sameBucket(left, right)`, then all values between `left` and `right` must belong to the same bucket as well.

> I believe a modified binary search should be able to perform this partitioning efficiently

Yes, you can run a binary search, like this:

1. set `nextBucket` to zero
2. set `left` to `nextBucket` and `right` to the end of the input array
3. set `mid` to midpoint between `left` and `right`
4. if `sameBucket(nextBucket, mid)` is `true`, move `left` to `mid`; otherwise, move `right` to `mid`
5. if `left == right`, exit the loop; otherwise, go back to step 3
6. Once the loop is done, `left` is the next partition index. All items between `nextBucket` and `left` are in the same bucket.
7. Set `nextBucket` to `left+1`
8. If `nextBucket` is equal to `n`, you are done; otherwise, go back to step 2.

I don't think this algorithm has a special name - it is a poorly disguised binary search.

Comment: If your assumption is true, can't you solve this in O(N) by walking through the items and recording the indexes where `sameBucket(A[i], A[i+1]) == false` ?

Comment: @AShelly Sure, I can. But since OP wants O(b * log(N)) algorithm, I assume that the number of buckets is very small in relation to N.

Comment: @AShelly For example, if you anticipate four buckets in a set of 1,000,000 items, O(b * log(N)) would require roughly 80 probes, vs. 1,000,000 probes for O(n) solution.

Comment: Yes – the expectation is that the number of buckets is << the number of elements. I think there is a somewhat more efficient algorithm – particularly if intervals are _not_ uniformly distributed, but tend to be clustered. I'll try to write it up. Basically though, _if_ the initial interval isn't in one bucket, you subdivide it. At least one (and possibly both) of the bottom and top intervals must not be in one bucket. For any that aren't, you subdivide again. In this way the bisection can "fan out" as required to find all buckets.

Comment: @Benjohn Of course, you can speed things out - all I wanted to achieve was getting the target asymptotic speed. Every time you discover an inequality in bucket indication you can create a new partition between the two elements, which you can later move to the exact position by looking at the range between two items that produced `false` in the call of `sameBucket`.

Comment: I [wrote up](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44384560/2547229) a second algorithm that might interest you – thanks for your answer. I'd still love to know if there's a name for the algorithm or the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to dasblinkenlight for [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44269231/2547229).

I was pretty sure that there was an algorithm for this with better big O performance than the approach they gave (which does have the asymtotic complexity I mentioned in the OP). I wrote it last night, and it goes like this.

```
bucket_starts(in_inclusive_range: r)
{
  if r.count is 0 or 1 elements
  {
    // There are no bucket starts in this range.
    // Return an empty array.
    return []
  }
  else
  {
    // If `r`'s start & end elements are in the same bucket
    // then `r` contains no bucket starts.
    if same_bucket(element_at[r.first_index], element_at[r.last_index])
    {
      // There are no buckets in this range.
      return []
    }
    else
    {
      // `r` has 1 or more buckets in it. Subdivide and find them.
      // Note that `midpoint` is in both lower & upper ranges.
      let first_subrange = range(from: r.first_index to: r.mid_index)
      let second_subrange = range(from: r.mid_index to: r.last_index)
      return bucket_starts(in_inclusive_range: first_subrange) + 
             bucket_starts(in_inclusive_range: second_subrange)
    }
  }
}
```

## Time Complexity

If the input has `n` elements, and contains `b` different buckets, then (I *believe*) the runtime complexity of the algorithm is *worst case* `O(b.log(n/b))`.

- In the limiting case that every input element falls in a different bucket, `b == n` and the cost becomes linear in `n`.
- For a given `b`, the worst case complexity occurs when all the bucket have uniform size. If most of the buckets are small and a few are large, the run time complexity will be reduced.
- For a sequence of output bucket sizes `B`, where `sum(B) == n`, the complexity will be something like: `O(sum_of_logs_of_B)`.
- In the extreme case of `b-1` buckets of size 1, and a 1 larger bucket size `n-b`, this will approach `O(b + log(n))`

This seems like a nice complexity behaviour. It adapts to the specifics of the content and has absolute worst case time performance linear in input size.

I don't know if there's a name for this – I very much doubt it is original! If you know the name, I'd like to know what it is.

## Space complexity

The space complexity needed for the algorithm (not it's input or output) is `O(log(n))`, so is overwhelmed by the linear storage for input and output.