# Implement `Array` & `ArraySlice` extension with a protocol instead

Tags: swift, generics

I have the following Swift code:

```
extension Array {
  typealias EqualTest = (Iterator.Element, Iterator.Element) -> Bool

  func groupSplitIndices(withEqualTest equal: EqualTest) -> [Index] {
    return indices.groupSplitIndices(withEqualTest: {equal(self[$0], self[$1])})
  }
}

extension ArraySlice {
  typealias EqualTest = (Iterator.Element, Iterator.Element) -> Bool
  
  func groupSplitIndices(withEqualTest equal: EqualTest) -> [Index] {
    return indices.groupSplitIndices(withEqualTest: {equal(self[$0], self[$1])})
  }
}

extension CountableRange {
  typealias EqualTest = (Element, Element) -> Bool
  
  func groupSplitIndices(withEqualTest equal: EqualTest) -> [Element] {
    // Implementation omitted here.
    // For details see  "Background" at the end of the question.
  }
}
```

Rather than extend `Array` and `ArraySlice` with identical code, is there a protocol I can extend that will achieve the same result?

Essentially, I would like to extend any collection where the associated type `Indices` is a `CountableRange`.

## Attempts at a generic implementation

I've tried to express this in many ways, but I've not found a way to make it compile.

## Attempt 1

```
extension RandomAccessCollection {
  typealias EqualTest = (Iterator.Element, Iterator.Element) -> Bool

  func groupSplitIndices(withEqualTest equal: EqualTest) -> [Index] {
    // Error on next line…
    return indices.groupSplitIndices(withEqualTest: {equal(self[$0], self[$1])})
  }
}
```

This attempt gives 2 errors:

> Value of type 'Self.Indices' has no member 'groupSplitIndices'
>
> Closure use of non-escaping parameter 'equal' may allow it to escape

(I think the second error is Swift getting confused.)

## Attempt 2

```
extension RandomAccessCollection where Indices: CountableRange {
  // Implementation omitted.
}
```

Gives error:

> Reference to generic type 'CountableRange' requires arguments in <...>

## Attempt 3

```
extension RandomAccessCollection where Indices: CountableRange<Int> {
  // Implementation omitted.
}
```

Gives error:

> Type 'Indices' constrained to non-protocol type 'CountableRange'

---

## Background

Here's the extension on `CountableRange` implementing `groupRanges(withEqualTest:)` that is omitted above. The algorithm, what it does, and it's Big O cost is discussed [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44268471/2547229).

I have attempted to implement something similar as an extension of `RandomAccessCollection`, but didn't have much luck.

```
extension CountableRange {
  typealias EqualTest = (Element, Element) -> Bool
  
  func groupRanges(withEqualTest equal:EqualTest) -> [CountableRange] {
    let groupIndices = groupSplitIndices(withEqualTest: equal)
    return groupIndices.indices.dropLast().map {groupIndices[$0]..<groupIndices[$0+1]}
  }
  
  func groupSplitIndices(withEqualTest equal: EqualTest) -> [Element] {
    var allIndexes = [lowerBound]
    allIndexes.append(contentsOf: interiorGroupSplitIndices(withEqualTest: equal))
    allIndexes.append(upperBound)
    
    return allIndexes
  }
  
  func interiorGroupSplitIndices(withEqualTest equal: EqualTest) -> [Element] {
    var result = Array<Element>()
    var toDo = [self]
    
    while toDo.count > 0 {
      let range = toDo.removeLast()
      
      guard
        let firstElement = range.first,
        let lastElement = range.last,
        firstElement != lastElement,
        !equal(firstElement, lastElement) else {
          continue;
      }
      
      switch range.count {
      case 2:
        result.append(lastElement)
      default:
        let midIndex = index(firstElement, offsetBy: range.count/2)
        toDo.append(range.suffix(from: midIndex))
        toDo.append(range.prefix(through: midIndex))
      }
    }
    
    return result
  }
}
```

Comment: Would it be an option to implement the code for RandomAccessCollection instead of CountableRange? – Then you can easily forward the call from an arbitrary RandomAccessCollection to its indices.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks – I've added some more to the question about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to call `indices.groupSplitIndices()` you need the constraint
`Indices == CountableRange<Index>` on the collection extension, 
and that requires `Index` to be `Strideable`:

```
extension RandomAccessCollection where Index: Strideable, Indices == CountableRange<Index> {

    typealias EqualTest = (Iterator.Element, Iterator.Element) -> Bool

    func groupSplitIndices(withEqualTest equal: EqualTest) -> [Index] {
        return indices.groupSplitIndices(withEqualTest: {
            equal(self[$0], self[$1])
        })
    }
}

extension CountableRange {
    typealias EqualTest = (Element, Element) -> Bool

    func groupSplitIndices(withEqualTest equal: EqualTest) -> [Element] {
        // Dummy implementation:
        return []
    }
}
```

and this actually compiles with Swift 4 (Xcode 9 beta or Xcode 8.3.3 with the Swift 4 toolchain).

There is one problem though: The Swift 3 compiler in Xcode 8.3.3 crashes when compiling the
above code with the "Debug" configuration. That seems to be a compiler
bug, because it compiles without problem in the "Release" configuration,
and also with Xcode 9 or with Xcode 8.3.2 and the Swift 4 toolchain.

---

Here is a rough description how I figured out the above solution.
Let's start with your "Attempt 3":

```
extension RandomAccessCollection where Indices: CountableRange<Int>

// error: type 'Indices' constrained to non-protocol type 'CountableRange<Int>
```

`Indices` can not be a subclass of or a type adopting `CountableRange<Int>`, which means that we need a same-typre requirement:

```
extension RandomAccessCollection where Indices == CountableRange<Int>
```

This results in

```
// error: cannot subscript a value of type 'Self' with an index of type 'Int'
```

at `self[$0]` and `self[$1]`. The `subscript` method of `Collection`
takes a `Self.Index` parameter, so we change it to

```
extension RandomAccessCollection where Indices == CountableRange<Index>

// error: type 'Self.Index' does not conform to protocol '_Strideable'
```

So `Index` must be `Strideable`:

```
extension RandomAccessCollection where Index: Strideable, Indices == CountableRange<Index>
```

and that's it!

Comment: Thanks! This looks good. I've not had a chance to try out yet, but I'll accept when I've got it working. I was going to ask – "how do you know this"! I've found it frustrating with Swift to determine the constraints that I need, and generally to understand how the standard library's types and protocols fit together. It doesn't seem clear from the documentation, the errors can be misleading, and the standard library changed a lot between 2 & 3 (and will change again?).

Comment: @Benjohn: I have added some explanations.But a lot of try and error was involved as well!

Comment: Okay, that's brilliant, actually! Thank you! :-) … I'll follow your process through on my own code and try to recreate. It's interesting that the errors are fairly unhelpful! Eg `error: type 'Indices' constrained to non-protocol type 'CountableRange<Int>`, a more helpful error might be `error: Type constraint can only be used with protocol type, not with a struct type 'CountableRange<Int>'. Use the same-type requirement '==' for a struct instead.  – fix it?` Also, my toolchain being a version back didn't help – will upgrade once I manage to unpack the enormous xcode instal.

Comment: One more questions, if you can please – Is there some way I can give a name / alias to `RandomAccessCollection where Index: Strideable, Indices == CountableRange<Index>`, such as `CountableRangeIndicesRandomAccessCollection`? So that I can then just write `extension CountableRangeIndicesRandomAccessCollection {…`? It'd be nice to be able to isolate the idea of collections that have a countable range for their indices. Or, an integer for their index, etc.

Comment: @Benjohn: I don't know, but I assume not.